# Create tuples in Python from an XML String/File

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I've decided it'd be nice to have a way to generically create a dictionary from an `XML` string.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

response = '<some><generic><xml></xml></generic></some>'
targetTree = ET.fromstring(response)

# Do something cool here

for key in my_cool_dict:
    print '{0} = {1}'.format(key, my_cool_dict[key])
```

I've found nifty ways of iterating through your elements:

```
for elem in targetTree.findall('some'):
    for child in elem.getchildren():
        print i.text
```

These kinds of things require I know the `XML` tags.  What if I don't know what I'm receiving?  How can I create `my_cool_dict` where the `key` is the name of the tag and the `value` is the value between the tags?

Comment: Are you sure you'll never receive array-like data? `<container><item>a</item><item>b</item><item>c</item></container>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is flat (that is, the dictionary will not contain other dictionaries), then this should work:

```python
my_cool_dict = {}
for element in some_parent_element:
    my_cool_dict[element.tag] = element.text
```

For example, if  `some_parent_element` represents this element:

```xml
<question>
    <title>How do I make a `dict` from XML in Python?</title>
    <tags>python xml</tags>
    <body>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</body>
</question>
```

Then run your code:

```python
for key in my_cool_dict:
    print '{0} = {1}'.format(key, my_cool_dict[key])
```

You'll get this:

```
body = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
tags = python xml
title = How do I make a `dict` from XML in Python?
```